# Changing section divider size depending on screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to re-create the section dividers on https://sparktoro.com/. Notice how the size of the dividers (the zigzag and wavy lines) change depending on the screen size. For example, on a small screen there could be 3 peaks and on a large screen there could be 10 peaks.

In my version, the # of peaks remains the same and instead the image just stretches out. This causes the divider to look blurry and distorted.

I've tried to add the dividers as images in the HTML and setting the width to 100%.

```
<header class="grey-bg">
   <img class="header__logo" src="https://sparktoro.com/img/sparktoro-logo.c08f697d63cf1cb31c7388dd16efbfa9.svg">
</header>
<div class="white-bar">
   <img class="zigzag" src="https://i.ibb.co/9YryFMN/zig.png">
</div>
<div class="blue-bg section"></div>
<div class="white-bar">
   <img class="wavy" src="https://i.ibb.co/xLT7Wh4/imageedit-5-8200179975.png">
</div>
```

```
*{
     margin: 0;
}

 header{
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
}

 .header__logo{
     width: 200px;
     padding: 25px;
     text-align: center;
}

 .grey-bg{
     background-color: #f4f4f4;
     background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='4' height='4' viewBox='0 0 4 4'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23d8d8d8' fill-opacity='0.4' d='M1 3h1v1H1V3zm2-2h1v1H3V1z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

 .blue-bg{
     background-color: #c4e3e8;
     background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='4' height='4' viewBox='0 0 4 4'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23b9dfe5' fill-opacity='0.4' d='M1 3h1v1H1V3zm2-2h1v1H3V1z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

 .white-bar{
     height: 10px;
     position: relative;
}

 .section{
     height: 300px;
}

 .zigzag{
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: -10px;
     height: 30px;
}

 .wavy{
     width: 100%;
     height: 30px;
     position: absolute;
     top: -10px;
}
```

I would like my dividers to respond to the screen size like on https://sparktoro.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way sparktoro.com implemented is by using a repeating image. So their svg is just a single "wave" that repeats so depending on screen size you get more or less "waves"

to get the same effect add this to your background

```
background: url(/img/wavy-line.svg) repeat-x center center;
```

This will repeat that img/svg over and over again on the x axis.

To see how you should make your svg check out theirs

https://sparktoro.com/img/wavy-line.svg

Comment: No problem! :) can you mark the answer as correct so others know as well. Cheers.